# How do I use discord.Reaction.count from the discord.py API?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to count how many reactions a discord message has however I am having trouble using the discord.Reaction.count method. My code I am using is below, when I run the command I get as far as `print('2')` and then it stops. I have no traceback to know what I am doing wrong. Any help on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

````
        name="Tally",
        aliases=["tally"],
        description=
        "Tally the results from a poll by it's poll ID shown in the footer of the poll embed",
        brief="Tally poll results",
        pass_context=True)
    async def tally(self, ctx, id):
        print('1')
        tally_message = await ctx.fetch_message(id)
        print('2')
        reaction_count = tally_message.Reaction.count
        print('3')
        print(reaction_count)```
````

Answer (score 1):

`Message` objects don't have an attribute called `Reaction`, `discord.Reaction` is a class and are in no way related.

But you can use `Message.reactions` and get a list of all `Reaction` objects on that message, on which you can use the count attribute.
If you want the count of all the reactions you would have to do something like

```py
async def tally(self, ctx, id):
    tally_message = await ctx.fetch_message(id)
    reaction_count = sum(reaction.count for reaction in tally_message.reactions)
    print(reaction_count)
```

Refer the docs it is really simple to understand. If you are a beginner in python, I'd suggest you learn the basics more.